# Why won't KeyListeners work when a JButton is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I am trying to remove from a specific frame panel#1 (which only contains a single JButton) and add to it panel#2, which contains some KeyEvents.

I was constantly getting a bug where the KeyEvents won't register, but while I was testing out some things, I found out that if I don't remove panel#1 and add panel#2 on top of the frame, the KeyListeners will register, only if the JButton on the panel#1 is not selected (only by pressing "TAB").

Can someone help me remove this bug?

**This is panel#2:**

```
public class paintTest  extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    public paintTest(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

**And this is the Main class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame mainMenu = new JFrame();
        drawMainMenu(mainMenu);

        mainMenu.setVisible(true);
        mainMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void drawMainMenu(JFrame frame)
    {
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 360, 300);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        JButton newGame = new JButton();
        newGame.setBounds(130, 120, 100, 30);
        newGame.setText("NEW GAME");    

        newGame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {
                paintTest gamePlay = new paintTest();

//              frame.remove(panel);  **HERE IS THE LINE OF CODE I WANT TO REMOVE**

                frame.add(gamePlay);

                frame.setBounds(0,0,512,512);

                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            }
        });
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(newGame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: I know that you suggested me using KeyBinding, but I am asking why is this happening

Comment: Yes, that is the best solution, but that is NOT what I am talking about. I stated multiple time the reason the key events are not being generated and gave you a solution. Read the comments. I should NOT have to repeat myself 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it, thank you all:
One way to fix this is to make the JButton non-focusable by using:

```
.setfocusable(false);
```

This way the JButton will not be focused and marked, but still, when entering Panel#2 you will need to press "TAB" to focus again on the new Panel, and for that java.awt.Robot can be of use:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```